# Phonegap/Cordova, Safely store/protect files

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm currently writing an app in Phonegap/Cordova.

The app I'm writing needs to be able to save/manipulate files for a few different purposes the main ones are;

1. Downloadable content
2. Settings

Now, I don't really like the idea of saving the settings to the filesystem- but I could deal with that. Content though I really don't want to write to the regular file system (not without some form of encryption anyway).

Are there any ways to safely store content that doesn't put it right out there? Basically provide at least a minimal level of protection for the content?

Thanks.

Comment: there is no safe way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12227258/995891

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for complete safety, more so safety from the average user. So far there's one cross platform way to store data through phonegap/cordova, which is simply putting it on the sdcard with no further hiding or protection or anything-- that's a bit too unsafe for my liking.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are talking about Android then you could look into using the [Application Preferences plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/AppPreferences) to store settings.

For downloadable content then you would want to store it on the internal file system. Each app has it's own private directory at /data/data/{package name} where {package name} is specific to your app.

Comment: is the /data/data path actually accessable through phonegap also?

Comment: Yes, but your app can only access it's own /data/data/{package name} directory as it doesn't have privileges to access the other directories.